# Calculate Within Subject Pearson R Correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
id value 1 value 2 
1    2.65   7.98
1    5.89   10.84
2    1.65   2.67 
2    6.89   4.89
3    5.89   6.98
3    4.23   1.98
```

So I have 3 participants, which were measured twice and I obtained 2 values each per measurement.
I now want to calculate within subject correlations (Pearsson R), so the correlation between value 1 and value 2 for each participant / each measurement.

Im struggling on how to do this.

Comment: You must be asking this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Using the `dplyr` package, you need to `group_by` your ID variable, then use `cor` for correlation, which takes method as an argument.

I've made a bigger version of your dataframe so the results are more sensible. If you only have two rows per ID, the correlation will always be one.

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
           value_1=c(2.65,5.89,1.65,6.89,5.89,4.23,5.89,1.65,2.65,3.89,5.89,4.23),       value_2=c(7.98,10.84,2.67,4.89,6.98,1.98,5.89,1.65,2.65,4.89,5.89,4.23))
```

Then group_by and take cor, with pearson, spearman, or kendall:

```
df%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  summarise(pearson = cor(value_1,value_2, method = "pearson"),
            spearman = cor(value_1,value_2, method = "spearman"))
```

That results in the following:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id pearson spearman
  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1   0.388    0.4  
2     2   0.864    0.949
3     3   0.931    0.8
```

Comment: This is wrong, see [Correlation among repeated measures - I need an explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44134/correlation-among-repeated-measures-i-need-an-explanation).

Comment: Post a correction? I'm open to the idea, but am pretty convinced it's not wrong.

Comment: You did, technically, answer OP's question, however the solution is still wrong since you did not take into account the dependence of observations (repeated measurements) of the participants, independence being a fundamental assumption of correlation. You can read more about it in this article which lists common misuses and abuses of it https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5079093/, relevant part being `Correlation analysis assumes that all the observations are independent of each other. Thus, it should not be used if the data include more than one observation on any individual.`

Comment: That makes sense! I can go around that by taking the mean from the two time points, so I have two means per participants right?

Comment: @Sofia Not really, that is a very commonly used approach in such cases because it is easy and simple, however it will probably still return incorrect results, although it's probably better than not doing it.